# Select and upload video in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm building a application that will be able to enable the user to  select a video from gallery and upload it to a database.

However, I'm unable to select and pass the selected video by the user to the a UIView/UIImageView.

For example, the user selects the video but when upon pressing "Choose" button, it is unable to compress and pass it to the UIView from the gallery. Upon compression, it will display this output [View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wte8.png)

The code below is my button that will allow the user to "Take Video" or "Select From Gallery"

```
@IBAction func videoBtn(_ sender: Any)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Pick Image Source", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let takePhotoBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Video", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let VideoViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VideoViewController") as! VideoViewController
        self.present(VideoViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    })

    let galleryBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Select from Gallery", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
        }
    })

    let cancelBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        // print("Cancel")
    })

    alert.addAction(takePhotoBtn)
    alert.addAction(galleryBtn)
    alert.addAction(cancelBtn)

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}
```

Comment: I would use `AVACaptureSession` for live video (from camera), and use `Photos` library to access the video in the gallery, then to display that video on screen I will use `AVPlayer` or `AVPlayerController`, then to send it to any server that you are using encode the video to `based 64`... UIImageVIew doesn't have that ability to play video

Comment: Share code of : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate . And UIImageView just show thumbnail of video.

Comment: what do you mean? @NguyenHoan

Comment: are you using imageView for adding video from gallery if yes, please make use of AVPlayer for it. imageView won't support such Content. before selecting data just check type of data you are picking up like  if (.video) add it to AVPlayer not uiimageView